# How can i make sure a vuex action has finished before the page loads

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I have 2 issues where i pull data from an api and use it. However, the page loads before the api request has completed.
My first problem is in the router. I have a requiresAuth, to check if i'm logged in, i have the following:
router:

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (!to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) return next(); // does not require auth, make sure to always call next()!
    if (store.getters.isLoggedIn) return next();
    store.dispatch('pullUserInfo').then(() => {
        if (store.getters.isLoggedIn) return next(); // logged in, move it
        next({
            path: '/login',
            { redirect: to.fullPath } // save the location we were at to come back later
        });
    });
});
```

store action:

```js
pullUserInfo(context) {
    fetch(`${process.env.VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT}/v3/user`)
        .then(async r => {
            if (r.status !== 200) return context.commit('setUserInfo', null);
            const json = await r.json();
            context.commit('setUserInfo', json);
    });
},
```

app constructor:

```js
createApp(App)
    .use(router)
    .use(store)
    .mount('#app-mount');
```

When refreshing, checking in devtools, my userInfo object has data. However this data is set after router.beforeEach checks

My second issue is similar. I populate a table with data from the store, however when refreshing the store value is `null` because the api request is still ongoing

How do i wait for my action to complete and assure data is present before continuing?
I am using the latest vuex, vue-router and vue3. Working with SFC's and initialized with vue cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning `fetch()`'s promise did the trick.
This answer was given in the official Vue Discord server

```js
pullUserInfo(context) {
    return fetch(`${process.env.VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT}/v3/user`)
        .then(async r => {
            if (r.status !== 200) return context.commit('setUserInfo', null);
            const json = await r.json();
            context.commit('setUserInfo', json);
    });
},
```